# C open() function fails. Are my parameters wrong?

Tags: c, file, posix

This function fails to open the file. Are my parameters wrong or what could be causing this problem?

```
    int CreateFile(const char *filename){
        char filepath[strlen(filename) + 3];
        sprintf(filepath, "./%s", filename);
        int fd = open(filepath, O_CREAT, O_APPEND, S_IWGRP);
        if(fd == -1) printf("file read failed\n");
        return fd;
    }
```

Xcode prints only "file read failed" to the console. I tried to run this via Terminal aswell but that didn't help either.

I fixed an issue pointed by NetMage:

```
int CreateFile(const char *filename){
    char filepath[strlen(filename) + 3];
    sprintf(filepath, "./%s", filename);
    int fd = open(filepath, O_CREAT|O_APPEND, S_IWGRP);
    if(fd == -1) printf("file read failed\n");
    return fd;
}
```

Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue

Comment: Just to be clear, you know it is failing to open because it is printing `"file read failed\n"`, right?

Comment: Yes, just edited that in.

Comment: You aren't opening the file for reading so that error message is more than a bit misleading...

Comment: True, I put that line there without too much thinking just to see if it gets printed.. Sorry

Comment: Hint: your code relies on the current working directory. What do you imagine the current working directory is? What is it really?

Comment: `perror(filepath)` (if called right after `open` has failed so no other function has a chance to change `errno`) will tell you why the call failed.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 - Verify that `filepath` is being set correctly, either by printing it to the terminal or examining it in a debugger.

Step 2 - Verify that the file exists *in that path*, and that its permissions are set so that you can open it.  If `filepath` is `"./foo"`, then a file named `foo` had better exist in the *current working directory* (the directory from which you ran the program), and it needs to have at least read permission.

Step 3 - If the file does not exist, verify that you have permission to create new files in the current working directory.

Step 4 - If after doing all of that you still get an error, check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).  It will give you some additional information beyond "it didn't work."

```
#include <errno.h>
...
if(fd == -1) 
{
  switch( errno )
  {
    case EACCESS: // permission issues
      handle_permission_issue();
      break;

    case EEXIST: // file already exists and you used O_CREAT and O_EXCL
      handle_already_exists_issue();
      break;

    case EFAULT: // bad path
      handle_bad_path_issue()
      break;

    ...
  }
  printf("file read failed\n");
}
```

NetMage has pointed out one problem - your flags need to be bitwise-OR'd together, rather than listed as separate arguments.  Surprised the compiler didn't yell at you over that.

Comment: Shouldn't the O_CREAT flag create a new file if one doesn't exist? How do I check my permission to create new files? And can the permissions be set from within the program?

Comment: @FrostyWhite: It should *if you have permissions to do so* in the current directory.  Since you mention XCode I assume you're on a Mac, so open a terminal window, navigate to the directory where you're running the program, then type `ls -lad $(pwd)`.  The leftmost column will show the permissions on that directory; it should look something like `drwxr-xr-x`.  This shows that the owner of the directory has read, write, and execute permission, while everyone else only has read and execute permission.

Comment: @FrostyWhite: Before getting into that, though, check the value of `errno` after attempting the open - it may be some other issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `open` function takes only one parameter for `oflags`, which must be bit-ored together:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int fd = open(filepath, O_CREAT|O_APPEND, S_IWGRP);
if (fd == -1) printf("file read failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

Comment: Then I would suggest printing/displaying `errno` so you know the error occurring, which is most likely you don't have permission to write the current directory.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to all of this tiny bit more advanced stuff, so how is that done?

Comment: I added some more code to output `errno` when `fd` is `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the POSIX documentation for `open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) (somewhat reformatted, and note the bolded text):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <sys/stat.h> #include <fcntl.h>
>
> int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Values for oflag are constructed by a bitwise-inclusive OR of flags
>   from the following list, defined in . **Applications shall
>   specify exactly one of the first five values** (file access modes)
>   below in the value of oflag:
>
> - `O_EXEC`
>     Open for execute only (non-directory files). The result is unspecified if this flag is applied to a directory.
> - `O_RDONLY`
>     Open for reading only.
> - `O_RDWR`
>     Open for reading and writing. The result is undefined if this flag is applied to a FIFO.
> - `O_SEARCH`
>     Open directory for search only. The result is unspecified if this flag is applied to a non-directory file.
> - `O_WRONLY`
>     Open for writing only.
>
> ...

You need to include at least one of those five flags, perhaps like:

```
int fd = open(filepath, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, S_IWGRP);
```

Note that other failures may still occur.  As noted in the comments, you're prepending `"./"` to the file name, which may cause problems if, for example, you get passed `"/tmp/filename"` and the `tmp` directory doesn't exist in your current working directory, as `open()` will not create missing directories in any path.